# Dynamically updated datalist won't show

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, html-datalist

I'm updating an html5 datalist dynamically, as the user types, with the following script:

```
$('#place').on('keyup', function() {
    $.post('content/php/autocomp.php', { field: 'plaats', val: $('#place').val() }).done(function(response) {
        $('#autocomp-places').html(response);
    });
});
```

Which works fine except that the datalist often doesn't show right away. When I inspect the element the html is there but the datalist is not shown as soon as it's updated. How can I force it to show?

For the record: it works... I just wish it would always show the new suggestion right away.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am starting to struggle with this now as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just have found a decent workaround for this!

Here is my pseudo-code:

1. As I type, I make async httprequests to get data.
2. When data is returned, i clear and re-populate the datalist.
3. If the current input field is still focused, manually call [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) on the input element (this seems to force the data-list popup behavior to occur).

Answer (score 1):

Please use success instead of done method of ajax and try again.

```
$('#place').on('keyup', function () {
    $.post('content/php/autocomp.php', {
        field: 'plaats',
        val: $('#place').val()
    }).success(function (response) {
        $('#autocomp-places').html(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would try to use one of already available solutions such as the [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). It will shorten your development time and make the code free of typical bugs (not to mention getting the benefits from someone else work in the future).

If you really want to create your own version, I would make sure the list is cleared and repopulated with the following code:

```
$('#place').on('keyup', function() {
  var posting = $.post('content/php/autocomp.php', { field: 'plaats', val: $('#place').val() });
  posting.done(function(data) {
    $('#autocomp-places').empty().append(data);
  });
});
```